# Double click for selenium chromedriver is acting as a single click.

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Robot framework for automation testing and at one particular element I need to test for double click. But it seems that while running the tests chromedriver for selenium is taking the double click event is acting as a single click itself and performing the functionality written for single click. The same thing works as it should while testing with Firefox though.

I was a little curious as to is "Double Click" keyword not supported in chromedriver at all? If not is there any other work-around/alternative to achieve this ?

Snippet of code:

```html
Double click Element  xpath=.//*[@class='graph-node-group']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the selenium2library?

Comment: Yes I am using selenium2library.

Comment: Have you tried using raw selenium double click, ie: `Selenium2library.Double Click Element` or just using two clicks? `Selenium2library.Click Element` `Selenium2library.Click Element`

Comment: I tried the raw "Selenium2library.Double Click Element" it did not work. And wouldn't using two "Selenium2library.Click Element Selenium2library.Click Element" would be wrong ? I mean there is already something else happening on the click event. It would execute that and then move on.

Comment: Doing some research there is a few old issues with double click not working. Are you using the most up to date versions of chrome driver and selenium?

Comment: Yes. I am using the latest ones. Not able to find any related issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I was able to find that second perform() fixes the issue

```
elem = self.wd.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
actions = ActionChains(self.wd)
actions.double_click(elem).perform()
actions.perform()
```